# Mongodb query using mgov2

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have a collection of endpoint point tests conducted on various channels. A sample document from the collection is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59959b30c699811077751b12"),
    "teststatus" : "Fail",
    "channelname" : "HouseController",
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-08-17T13:15:53.170Z"),
    "testid" : "llpKIgIfiiquqkSApwNn"
}
```

I am querying this to project the result something like this:

```
[
  {
    "Fail": 20,
    "Success Count": 30,
    "Total": 50,
    "channel": "c3"
  }, ...
```

But I am getting the wrong count for success and fail rate. My current query in golang looks like:

```
o1:=  bson.M{
    "$project" :bson.M{
        "channel": "$channelname",
        "time":"$timestamp",
        "teststatus" : "$teststatus",
        "_id":1,
    },
}
o2:=  bson.M{
    "$group" :bson.M{
        "_id": "$channel",
        "Success": bson.M{
            "$sum":bson.M{ "$eq" :"teststatus","Pass"},
        },
        "Total": bson.M{
            "$sum": 1,
        },
    },
}
o3:=  bson.M{
    "$project" :bson.M{
        "channel": "$_id",
        "Success Count":"$Success",
        "Total" : "$Total",
        "_id":0,
        "Fail": bson.M{
            "$subtract": []interface{}{"$Total", "$Success"},
        },
    },
}
```

I am doing wrong in the counting of success count. I just cant figure to do it right. I have just started with mgo and golang.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$cond` to do conditional counting. For example the following counts all tests, failed ones and successful ones in one step:

```
o2 := bson.M{
    "$group" :bson.M{
        "_id": "$channel",
        "Total": bson.M{
            "$sum": 1,
        },
        "Success": bson.M{"$sum": bson.M{
            "$cond": []interface{}{
                bson.M{ "$eq": []interface{}{"$teststatus", "Pass"}},
                1, 0,
            },
        }},
        "Fail": bson.M{"$sum": bson.M{
            "$cond": []interface{}{
                bson.M{"$eq": []interface{}{"$teststatus", "Fail"}},
                1, 0,
            },
        }},
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks @icza. I have messed up with the db. I shall test it and respond today itself

Comment: it is giving error:
`mongodb\task2\task2.go:78: missing key in map literal`
`mongodb\task2\task2.go:84: missing key in map literal`
on line:
`bson.M{ "$eq" :"$teststatus", "Pass"}`
and,
`bson.M{"$eq" :"$teststatus", "Fail"}`
@icza

Comment: @PrinceRaj Right. Fixed. Try again.

Comment: [
  {
    "Fail": 0,
    "Success": 0,
    "Total": 100,
    "_id": null
  }
]
Its giving wrong data @icza

Comment: @PrinceRaj it works for me locally. Please show how you execute the whole query.

Comment: watch here https://play.golang.org/p/JaeOFR881l
@icza
May be I am doing some typo

Comment: @PrinceRaj The reason why it doesn't work for you because in you example code your project the `teststatus` field to `status`, but in your question you mapped `teststatus` to `teststatus`! Use this code if you want to keep the shorter `status` name: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bn6-x_sv8Q)